# Groovy remove Collection item while iterating

Tags: groovy

Is there a Groovy way of removing a Collection's item while iterating? In Java this is accomplished using `Iterator.remove()`:

```
Collection collection = ...
for (Iterator it=collection.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Object obj = it.next();
    if (should remove) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Does Groovy provide remove-while-iterating in its language syntax, or do I have do use `Iterator.remove()`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Use `removeAll()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.lang.Object[]%29).

```
> c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> c.removeAll { it % 2 == 0 }
> println c
[1, 3, 5]
```

You ask specifically about "while iterating", are you trying to do something with/too each object? `removeAll` still works as long as the closure's last statement is still truthy/falsey (as before):

```
> c.removeAll { 
*     tmp = it * 10
*     println "ohai ${it}*10=${tmp}"
*     tmp >= 40
* }
ohai 1*10=10
ohai 2*20=20
ohai 3*30=30
ohai 4*40=40
ohai 5*50=50
> println c
[1, 2, 3]
```

The closure's return value (value of the last statement, or an explicit `return` value) is truthy/falsey, it will be used to determine what should be removed. It doesn't need to refer explicitly to each object.

Comment: @JarredOlson If you are new to Groovy I'd suggest you restrain yourself from doing manual iterator-based loops (or `for (<three statements here>)` for loops). With closure-based methods like `each`, `collect`, `findAll`, etc I have never had the need to use explicit iterators in Groovy, and that has been a great relief =D

Comment: @epidemian I'm not new, just didn't know about .removeAll {} and I just thought it was cool :)  I would echo your statements though in that using the methods on Collection are very good ways to get familiar with closures/Groovy.

Comment: FYI `removeAll(Closure)` is only available in 1.7.2 or later.

Comment: @JarredOlson Sorry, I didn't realize you were not the OP. Still, I'd hold the advice for anyone new to the language =D