# need help removing an item from a collection of objects

Tags: groovy

I am working on a performance review application. I have a collection that tracks responses from various individuals. This particular closure will collect the scores from all the evaluations

```
    def scores = responses.collectEntries { Category key, Collection<Response> value ->
        [(key): value.score]
    }
```

This is the structure of the `value` parameter, being passed in the closure

http://snag.gy/q4OEq.jpg

I am trying to remove a score from being added to the `[(key):value.score]`. More specifically, I'm trying to prevent someones `self` evaluation from being added.

I've tried several things. This being two of them.

```
    def scores = responses.collectEntries { Category key, Collection<Response> value ->

        for (i in value) {
            if (i.evaluation.respondent == i.evaluation.performanceReview.employee) {
                //didn't work
                value.remove(i)

                // also didn't work
                value - i
            }
        }

        [(key): value.score]
    }
```

The if statement works fine, it will hit the inside conditions when there is a self evaluation. It's what's inside the if statment that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808594/438992

Comment: thanks, I found this comment to be particularly useful,  'If you are new to Groovy I'd suggest you restrain yourself from doing manual iterator-based loops (or for (<three statements here>) for loops). With closure-based methods like each, collect, findAll, etc I have never had the need to use explicit iterators in Groovy, and that has been a great relief =D'

Comment: Yep, epidemian has it right; you only rarely need such constructs in when you have the more functionally-oriented constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you get rid of the `for` loop and just have:

```
    [ key,
      value.findAll {
          it.evaluation.respondent != it.evaluation.performanceReview.employeescore
      }.score ]
```

As the body of the `collectEntries` call?